# Vue 2 and Nuxt: variable href inside a v-for (Vuex stateful variables)

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use string interpolation to create an href inside a component v-for loop:

```
<template>
  <div class="pa4">
    <div v-for="item in navigationItems">
      <a href="'#'${item}">{{item}}</a>
    </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {mapState} from 'vuex'
  export default {
    computed: {
      ...mapState({
      navigationItems: state => state.navigationItems
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

Navigation items originate in the Vuex store:

```
export const state = {
  navigationItems: ['Home', 'About', 'Blog', 'Contact']
}
```

Angular JS has an ng-href directive that would be perfect: 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

When I use v-bind:href="item" I get 'not bound' errors. Any ideas how to pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `mapState` is working it should be

```
<a :href="'#'+item">{{item}}</a>
```

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/zwoEdJ?editors=1010).